# DatabaseType not found for product name: [Apache Hive] in spring batch

Tags: java, hive, spring-batch

Our current application having Spring batch Jobs works with RDBMS (Oracle). As part of strategic roadmap all the data will be in HIVE and there will be no dependency on Oracle (RDBMS). As part of this roadmap, we are trying to do POC to verify the feasibility of executing Spring Batch against Hive. However, when we have the HIVE JDBC driver configured and trying the deploy the application locally in JBOSS, we are getting the exception as "**DatabaseType not found for product name: [Apache Hive]**”. This issue was coming due the configurations of `JobRepository` and also `JsrJobParametersConverter`as both of them look for Database type of data source Product name. As we see the class *org.springframework.batch.support.**DatabaseType*** (**`spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar`**) ***does not supports HIVE***.

As we could not find any solution, we followed the guidelines (though limited) which are provided in the section Spring batch documentation "*4.3.4 Non-standard Database Types in Repository*" 
 https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/index-single.html

- Extended the `JobRepositoryFactoryBean` with customized class `JobRepositoryFactoryBeanForHive`
- Implemented the various DAO interfaces on which `SimpleJobRepository` depends on as. This is done to have control on these DAO implementations as they are responsible for persisting batch metadata in database.

  1. JobInstanceDao (`HiveJdbcJobInstanceDao`)
  2. JobExecutionDao (`HiveJdbcJobExecutionDao`)
  3. StepExecutionDao (`HiveJdbcStepExecutionDao`)
  4. ExecutionContextDao (`JdbcHiveExecutionContextDao`)
- Hive does not has the support for Sequences. As a workaround, Created a table to add / increment the Id and keep on retrieving the max value for each hit to table
- Implemented `HiveIncrementerFactory` (factory for creating implementation of `HiveIncrementer`) and related `HiveIncrementer` (to retrieve the next value from the table created for sequence )
- Modified the implementation of the method `determineClobTypeToUse()` in `JobRepositoryFactoryBeanForHive`  to set Types to `VARCHAR`. In the database the field **`SERIALIZED_CONTEXT`** has been declared with datatype as `VARCHAR` as Hive does not support `CLOB`. At max, 2 GB can be stored. (As CLOB in Oracle can be **8 GB**, should there be 3 fields created to store context by splitting if more than **2 GB** in each of these fields)

  ```
  <bean id="jobRepository" class="com.batch.springutil.JobRepositoryFactoryBeanForHive">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
        <property name="databaseType" value="oracle" />  
        <property name="incrementerFactory" ref="hiveIncrementerFactory" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="isolationLevelForCreate" value="ISOLATION_DEFAULT" />
  </bean> 
  <bean id="hiveIncrementerFactory" class="com.batch.springutil.HiveIncrementerFactory">
            <constructor-arg ref="DataSource" /> 
  </bean>
  ```
- Implemented customized class `JsrJobParametersConverterHive` extending `JsrJobParametersConverter`

  ```
  <bean id="jobParametersConverter" class="com.batch.springutil.JsrJobParametersConverterHive">
        <constructor-arg ref="BatchDataSource" />
  </bean>
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to section [4.3.4 Non-standard Database Types in Repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/index-single.html#nonStandardDatabaseTypesInRepository) from the docs:

> If even that doesn’t work, or you are not using an RDBMS, then the only option may be to implement the various Dao interfaces that the SimpleJobRepository depends on and wire one up manually in the normal Spring way.

Since you have implemented the 4 DAOs that the job repository depends on, you can create a bean of type `SimpleJobRepository` and wire your DAOs in it. In other words, do not use the `JobRepositoryFactoryBean` and create the bean yourself:

```
@Bean
public SimpleJobRepository hiveJobRepository(
    HiveJdbcJobInstanceDao hiveJdbcJobInstanceDao,
    HiveJdbcJobExecutionDao hiveJdbcJobExecutionDao,
    HiveJdbcStepExecutionDao hiveJdbcStepExecutionDao,
    JdbcHiveExecutionContextDao jdbcHiveExecutionContextDao) {

    return new SimpleJobRepository(hiveJdbcJobInstanceDao, hiveJdbcJobExecutionDao,
                               hiveJdbcStepExecutionDao, jdbcHiveExecutionContextDao);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud Ben Hassine<BR> can you please let me know the below <BR/>

 - *Is there plan for spring Batch to include the support for Hive in future?*
<BR/>
 - *Is Spring batch recommended to run the batch jobs against Hive, or, should the tools like Apache spark should be used for Big data technology? We have currently the Java application having these spring batch jobs?*

Comment: There is no plan to support Hive, but feel free to open a feature request if you want. I can't give any recommendation in regards to using Spring Batch or Spark, because it depends on the use case. Take a look at this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53730498/5019386 which might help you in your decision.